# What is "Base Capacity Unit-Hour" in IBM Event Streams?

Tags: ibm-cloud

When choosing the Enterprise Plan for IBM Event Streams, there is a huge cost associated for Base Capacity Unit-Hour which costs more than $5K per month if I put 720 hours in it (assuming 1 month is 720 hours).

This makes it way too expensive and made me wonder if I understood correctly what "Base Capacity Unit-Hour" means.

Comment: This is not a Stack Overflow question, but something for the IBM support (chat).

Comment: @data_henrik IBM suggested this question to be asked on SO.

Comment: IBM support suggested this?

Comment: @data_henrik I can show you the SS, their support size suggests using SO.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this from an IBM rep:

> The price is 6.85/Base Capacity Unit, and that's by the hour. So broken down we have, 6.85 * 24 * 30 = 4932/month, which makes your estimate correct. Base Capacity Unit covers 150 MB/s(3 brokers) and 2TB storage. If you find you need to scale up, then the rate will increase from there.